# How can I get url of image variant in model (outside of controller/view)? Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I can get url in model with this code (Active Storage)

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(picture_of_car, only_path: true)`

But I need to get url of a resized variant

`picture_of_car.variant(resize: "300x300").processed`

For example this code

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(picture_of_car.variant(resize: "300x300").processed, only_path: true)`

throw

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `signed_id' for #< ActiveStorage::Variant:0x0000000004ea6498 >):
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Solution:

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(picture_of_car.variant(resize: "300x300").processed, only_path: true)`

Answer provided [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32500#issuecomment-380004250).

> for a variant you need to use rails_representation_url(variant) - this will build a url similar to the one that rails_blob_url builds but specifically for that variant.

Comment: You can remove the `.processed` in order to have this lazily executed when the image is first fetched. You can also remove `only_path: true` and just call `rails_representation_path` instead of `rails_representation_url`.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
variant = picture_of_car
            .variant(resize: '300x300')
            .processed 

variant.service.send(:path_for, variant.key) # Absolute path to variant file
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html it should be:
`picture_of_car.variant(resize: [300, 300]).processed.service_url`

Comment: you are not right - in section related to `service_url` it is written that you shouldn't use it directly, instead use `url_for(variant)`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding on here, if you're just needing a url for an Active Storage attachment to pass to an HTML element that Rails doesn't have a native `*_tag` method for, you can use `url_for` in scope and it'll work. In my case it was a `<picture>` tag. For an image it's easy:

```
<%= image_tag @thing.foo_image.variant(:medium), class: "mx-auto" %>
```

For a `<picture>` tag (no native `picture_tag` helper) it's almost as easy:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="<%= url_for(@thing.foo_image.variant :large) %>">
```