ActiveStorage - Rails API Only
I have a rails-api-only application and want to upload a Logo.

Using Rails 7, Ruby 3.1.2
Gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

Able to upload Logo and retrieve the original logo using following methods.
class CloudOperator < ApplicationRecord

  has_one_attached :op_logo do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_limit: [100, 100]
  end

  def op_logo_url
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(op_logo) if op_logo.attached?
  end
end

The following command in terminal provides the url
CloudOperator.last.op_logo_url

"http://localhost:3001/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--d38ae8737261881a9cf099fdb2de584a367641/2chDe_kw.jpg"

How to get the thumb variant URL?
Using carrier-wave its easy but don't want to install the additional gem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128695/activestorage-get-variant-url-in-model

Using the following
def op_logo_thumb_url 
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(op_logo.variant(:thumb))
end

Initially, i was getting errors
LoadError (Could not open library 'vips.42': dlopen(vips.42, 0x0005): tried: 'vips.42' (no such file)

So Installed the missing dependency
brew install vips

All working now.
Thank you

While answering your own questions can be a good way to share knowledge if the answer is something that isn't actually directly tied to the original question it's not very likely to be helpful to others and you should instead just consider deleting the question. A litmus test to see if your question is still valid is if anyone else could answer the question given the information in it. In this case the answer is a solid no because you didn't actually write what the error you encountered was.

op_logo_thumb_url is the method that provides a variant URL.
In case if developer is using MAC, he might need to install the dependency. The answer is very clear with respect to question. I hope it will help others so not deleting it. @max

Its just going to get downvoted and closed anyways.

To retrieve the URL for the thumb variant of the logo using Active Storage (which is included in Rails), you can generate the variant URL using the rails_representation_url helper instead of url_for.


class CloudOperator < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :op_logo do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_limit: [100, 100]
  end

  def op_logo_url
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(op_logo) if op_logo.attached?
  end

  def op_logo_thumb_url
    if op_logo.attached?
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(
        op_logo.variant(:thumb).processed,
        only_path: true
      )
    end
  end
end



