# I got NoMethodError: undefined method `rails_blob_path` when using active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I got a following error when using active storage in rails 6.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `rails_blob_path' for #<Module:0x00007fb91cb006a8>
```

### My env

- rails 6.0.0(api mode)
- ruby '2.6.3'

I already installed active storage and execute migrate

### config/environments/development.rb

```rb
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

### Model

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_one_attached :original_file
end
```

### Serializer

```rb
class ContractSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  attributes :id, :original_file

  def original_file
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(object.original_file, only_path: true) if object.original_file.attached?
  end
end
```

If you have any tips, Please let me know if you know anything about this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `include` statement and the full path to `rails_blob_path` method seem to be OK.

It looks like there is a naming issue.
You have created `attribute` and `method` with the same name.
Try to change one of them.

Comment: I didn't include in my project and this helped. Thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this :

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_representation_url(object.original_file(resize: "300x300").processed, only_path: true)
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53547638/2679301